# Intercept http requests without creating a browser extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http

I'm currently trying to create an application to automate analytics testing, but I have no idea what to use or how to start. What I wanted to do is explained in the pic below

[image]

I want to read the headers because the request that corresponds to the analytics have specific attributes. Is it possible to access those requests without creating an extension? ( Preferably with jQuery or PHP )

Answer (score 0):

In php you can use [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php),

```
<?php
    foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name: $value\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried it but it only show the headers of the page request, ie: if I load a page called test.com it just shows the headers of the page.com request. See the image: http://imgur.com/ju0HgCu. The text with the black line is the URL of the page I requested. Any ideas? I'm pretty lost here